# Is call-template synchronous in WSO2

Tags: asynchronous, wso2, call, sequence, wso2-esb

I'm quite new to wso2 and when using call-template I've the felling that my sequence is not called a synchronous way (the call-template is actually done in iterate mediation with sequential="true").
Can someone confirm that call-template is synchronous and if not, how to make it synchronous.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the mediation contained in your template. For exemple :

- if you use clone mediator, it's targets are executed in new threads
  and the iterate will continue with the next item
- if you use send mediator, a callback is instanciated to receive the response and your iterate will continue the same way

Comment: Yes right thanks @jean-michel, I tried to remove some parts of my template to see which mediator was causing troubles. In my case it's a call to a http endpoint. From my understanding it was supposed to be synchronous. I'll try the blocking="true" attribute to see if it changes something.

Comment: Yes, call with blocking="true" offers you a way to make a synchronous call